# How to pin a header-logo, part of the batch code?

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off
Mode con cols=90 lines=50
color 0B
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=#" %%a in ('"prompt #$H#$E# & echo on & for %%b in (1) do rem"') do (set "DEL=%%a")
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "BotName=Amanda"
set "Name=Ikki"
set "Lines="
set "Columns="
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=: " %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\mode.com') do if "%%I" == "Lines" (set "Lines=%%J") else if "%%I" == "Columns" set "Columns=%%J"
<nul set /p=""
%SystemRoot%\System32\mode.com CON COLS=100 LINES=35
color 0b
echo/
echo/
title A.I. Chat Bot Amanda 0.2
echo.
echo                      __      ____       ___  _   _    __    ____    ____  _____  ____  
echo                     /__\    (_  _)     / __)( )_( )  /__\  (_  _)  (  _ \(  _  )(_  _)   
echo                    /(__)\    _)(_     ( (__  ) _ (  /(__)\   )(     ) _   )(_)(   )(    
echo                   (__)(__)()(____)()   \___)(_) (_)(__)(__) (__)   (____/(_____) (__)
echo.
echo                                  __    __  __    __    _  _  ____     __   
echo                                 /__\  (  \/  )  /__\  ( \( )(  _ \   /__\  
echo                                /(__)\  )    (  /(__)\  )  (  )(_) ) /(__)\ 
echo                               (__)(__)(_/\/\_)(__)(__)(_)\_)(____/ (__)(__)
echo.
echo.
echo                                        (Prototype Version 0.2)
echo/
echo.
echo.
ping localhost -n 3 > nul

ECHO >nul && call :PainText 0C %BotName%  
echo : Hello I'am A.I. Chatbot but my users call me Amanda.


:: How to make that the above logo does not move when writing with a bot? I would like the logo to be visible all the time (so that it is pinned in code), so that only the written text moves. I would also like a slider to scroll through the written chat, but I do not know what code to use.

:Begin 
echo.
ECHO >nul && call :PainText 9 "%Name%"
set "TALK="
set /P "TALK=: "
echo.
ECHO >nul && call :PainText 0C "%BotName%"
if not defined TALK echo : TYPE SOMETHING, PLEASE!& goto Begin
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "TALK=!TALK:?=!"
if not defined TALK endlocal & echo : TYPE SOMETHING, PLEASE!& goto Begin
set "TALK=!TALK:"= !"
set "TALK=!TALK:<= !"
set "TALK=!TALK:>= !"
set "TALK=!TALK:|= !"
set "TALK=!TALK:&= !"
set "TALK=!TALK:)= !"
endlocal & set "TALK=%TALK%"
if /I "%TALK%" == "exit" goto EndBatch

set "Output=:"


:: Text used by the bot, which I would like to move while writing, and the above logo: A.I. Chatbot Amanda, (Prototype Version 0.2) was pinned on top of the cod. I hope that my code and explanation are clear what I mean.                                                                                          

echo %TALK% | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /R "\<hi\>" >nul && call :Hi
echo %TALK% | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /R "\<hello\>" >nul && call :Hello
if "%Output%" == ":" set "Output=%Output% Sorry, I don't understand your last input."
echo %Output%
goto Begin

:Hi
:Hello
set /A Number=%RANDOM% %% 11
if %Number% == 0 set "Output=%Output% Hello, %name%!" & goto :EOF
if %Number% == 1 set "Output=%Output% What's up?" & goto :EOF
if %Number% == 2 set "Output=%Output% How is your day going?" & goto :EOF
if %Number% == 3 set "Output=%Output% Konichiwa %name%!" & goto :EOF
if %Number% == 4 set "Output=%Output% Yo!" & goto :EOF
if %Number% == 5 set "Output=%Output% Whazzup %name%!" & goto :EOF
if %Number% == 6 set "Output=%Output% Ohayo ;)" & goto :EOF
if %Number% == 7 set "Output=%Output% Hi I love you %name%!" & goto :EOF
if %Number% == 8 set "Output=%Output% Hi, what's up?" & goto :EOF
if %Number% == 9 set "Output=%Output% How's it going?" & goto :EOF
set "Output=%Output% Hey %Name%! Good to see you!" & goto :EOF

:: Because in the current situation when I write with a bot, the logo is scrolled and is invisible, and I would like it to be at the top all the time during the conversation. Is there any code in the batch that will allow me to pin the A.I. Chatbot Amanda, (Prototype Version 0.2) at the top, so that when I write with the bot the logo stays in place and does not move down with the written text?


:PainText
<nul set /p "=%DEL%" > "%~2"
findstr /v /a:%1 "+" "%~2" nul
del "%~2" > nul
goto :eof
```

:: Because in the current situation when I write with a bot, the logo is scrolled and is invisible, and I would like it to be at the top all the time during the conversation. Is there any code in the batch that will allow me to pin the A.I. Chatbot Amanda, (Prototype Version 0.2) at the top, so that when I write with the bot the logo stays in place and does not move down with the written text?

```
:EndBatch
color
if defined Lines if defined Columns %SystemRoot%\System32\mode.com CON COLS=%Columns% LINES=%Lines%
endlocal
```

Comment: So you're saying that you want to waste 16 lines of your 35 line screen realestate with a pointless picture. There is already a `Title` command which could assign the static string to the title bar of that Command Prompt window; `Title A.I. Chatbot Amanda, (Prototype Version 0.2)`. Currently your code does not attempt to do anything like what you are seeking as a goal, so what you appear to be wanting is a personal search assistant for research links, or somebody to code it for you. This site doesn't generally provide a free code writing or search assistant service, your question is off topic.

Answer (score 1):

An exmaple of using VT sequences for setting the scroll region:
`ESC[<t>;<b>r`, where `<t>` is an integer for the the top row and `<b>` is an integer for the bottom row.

Once the scroll margin is set, the cursor needs to be positioned to the new top margin.

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences) for more information about VT sequences including `ESC[E` linefeed, `ESCM` reverse linefeed, `ESC[<n>M` delete line/s and `ESC[<n>L` Insert line, all of which scroll the buffer as required.

Example:

```bat
@Echo off

:# Windows Version control. Assigns flag true if system is windows 10 build GTR 10586
:# https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#DOS,_OS/2,_and_Windows
:# Version 1511 build number = 10.0.10586
 Set "Win10="
 For /f "tokens=3 delims=." %%v in ('Ver')Do if %%v GTR 10586 Set "Win10=True"

:# If Win10 true ; Test if virtual terminal codes enabled ; enable if false
:# removes win10 flag definition if version does not support Virtual Terminal sequences
:# Reg values: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/understanding-windows-console-host-settings/
 If defined Win10 (
  Reg Query HKCU\Console | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /LIC:"VirtualTerminalLevel    REG_DWORD    0x1" > nul || (
    Reg Add HKCU\Console /f /v VirtualTerminalLevel /t REG_DWORD /d 1
  ) > Nul && (
    Echo(CMD restart required to enable Virtual terminal sequences.
    Pause
    EXIT
  ) || Set "Win10="
 )

 If not Defined Win10 (Echo(Unsupported & Exit /b 1)

 For /f Delims^= %%e in ('Echo prompt $E^|cmd')Do set \E=%%e
 Mode 200,40
 For /f "tokens=* Delims=:" %%G in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /blic:"::" "%~f0"')Do Echo(%%G
 <nul Set /p =%\E%[10;40r%\E%[10;1H

 for /? | more

Goto:Eof

::                      __      ____       ___  _   _    __    ____    ____  _____  ____  
::                     /__\    (_  _)     / __)( )_( )  /__\  (_  _)  (  _ \(  _  )(_  _)   
::                    /(__)\    _)(_     ( (__  ) _ (  /(__)\   )(     ) _   )(_)(   )(    
::                   (__)(__)()(____)()   \___)(_) (_)(__)(__) (__)   (____/(_____) (__)
::                                  __    __  __    __    _  _  ____     __   
::                                 /__\  (  \/  )  /__\  ( \( )(  _ \   /__\  
::                                /(__)\  )    (  /(__)\  )  (  )(_) ) /(__)\ 
::                               (__)(__)(_/\/\_)(__)(__)(_)\_)(____/ (__)(__)
::
```

Comment: What are all of these matching labels `:#` for T3RROR? I don't think that they really make the code look cleaner, and only really add confusion. What was wrong with using `Rem` or `@Rem` to correctly comment your script?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but the code you provided doesn't work for me, or I just can't apply it. @T3RR0R

Comment: How about you try to explain how the code is not working as intended @Ikki789. "The code you provided doesn't work for me" does not provide sufficient information for us to diagnose an issue. We expect, that you at least remove the first line, run the script from a Command Prompt window and then have access to every line of output. I will say however, that the solution submitted above, is designed for Windows 10 and newer, so if you're on an earlier OS, it will not work for you.